# Load a not SIlverlight dll into a Silverlight project type

Tags: c#, dll, silverlight-5.0

I hope isn't a stupid question...

Is possible to load a no silverlight assembly into a silverlight project without using a COM object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to Jens' answer, there is no other way to load .NET assemblies that are not simply Silverlight assemblies. You can load win32 dlls with P/Invoke on SL5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Portable Class Library (PCL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391.aspx)

> Use this project to write and build portable assemblies that work
>   without modification on multiple platforms, such as Windows 7, Windows
>   8, Silverlight, Windows Phone, and Xbox 360. For example, you can
>   create classes that contain shared business logic for desktop apps,
>   Windows Store apps, and mobile apps, and you can then reference those
>   classes from your apps.
>
> The Portable Class Library project supports a subset of assemblies
>   from the .NET Framework, Silverlight, .NET for Windows Store apps,
>   Windows Phone, and Xbox 360, and provides a Visual Studio template
>   that you can use to build assemblies that run without modification on
>   these platforms. If you don't use a Portable Class Library project,
>   you must target a single app type, and then manually rework the class
>   library for other app types. With the Portable Class Library project,
>   you can reduce the time and costs of developing and testing code by
>   building portable assemblies that are shared across apps for different
>   devices.

Also, Microsoft's **Scott Hanselman** has written a few articles about the PCL, this one should be a good starting point to find the resources you need to get started: [Cross-Platform Portable Class Libraries with .NET are Happening](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CrossPlatformPortableClassLibrariesWithNETAreHappening.aspx)